# Sharing a public tree in an ember-cli addon

Tags: ember-cli

I am completely puzzled when I read all the information I can gather about sharing a `public` assets directory from an `ember-cli` addon.

Is there anybody having it working around here? Any ref to an example addon doing it would also be appreciated...

Comment: I found that the *way* to do it is using the `treeForPublic` hook, but there isn't much documentation about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So... I finally found a way to share the static assets:
- I placed the files in `vendor/assets` directory
- Declared the files to shared (each file...) into the addon's `index.js` file @ addon's root

```js
app.import('vendor/assets/my_image.png');
```

An interesting option of `app.import` statement I found in my searches is `destDir`, which allows to customize the target publication path of the asset:

```js
app.import('vendor/assets/a/b/c/my_image.png', { destDir: 'x/y' });
```

will publish `my_image.png` @ URL `/assets/x/y/my_image.png`

Hoping this will help others to save time...

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it did saved my lots of time.

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assets of addons are available under a namespace. For example if there is a file in `public/assets/image.png` in your addon, this file is available under `/my-addon/assets/image.png`.

If you don't want to use a namespace, you can overwrite the `treeForPublic` hook in the addon definition as demonstrated in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/raido/87a461b896f9281ed574):

```
const Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');
const mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

module.exports = {
  name: require('./package').name,

  treeForPublic: function(tree) {
    const assetsTree = new Funnel('public');
    return mergeTrees([tree, assetsTree], {
      overwrite: true,
    });
  },
};
```